Create LV thinpool over two PVs prioritising the fast PV
I have two PVs in a VG, where /dev/sda1 is slow and /dev/sdb3 is fast. I want to create a 0.5TB LV thinpool that uses all of the fast disk and the remainder of the slow disk. I will use this for running VMs, and use the remainder of the slow disk for storing bulk data.
by default,
lvcreate --thin -L 0.5TB pve/thinpool_vms

creates it in the wrong order
If I provide the PVs as optional args, it doesn't work because it ignores the order:
lvcreate --thin -L 0.5TB pve/thinpool_vms /dev/sdb3 /dev/sda1

Specifying the extents to use also doesn't help:
lvcreate --thin -L 0.5TB pve/thinpool_vms /dev/sdb3:5632-59361 /dev/sda1

If I check the free extents on my fast PV, and create a volume with that size, it fails because it needs some overhead
lvcreate --thin -l53730 pve/thinpool_vms /dev/sdb3
  Thin pool volume with chunk size 128.00 KiB can address at most 31.75 TiB of data.
  Insufficient free space: 53757 extents needed, but only 53703 available

The best solution I now have is to subtract that overhead, then create a volume, check the resulting size, and expand to the desired size
lvcreate --thin -l53649 pve/thinpool_vms /dev/sdb3
  Thin pool volume with chunk size 128.00 KiB can address at most 31.75 TiB of data.
  Logical volume "thinpool_vms" created.
lvs -a | grep thinpool_vms
  thinpool_vms         pve twi-a-tz-- <209.57g             0.00   10.41                           
lvextend -L 0.5TB /dev/mapper/pve-thinpool_vms

Is there an easier way? And why do I need to use lvextend on /dev/mapper/pve-thinpool_vms? using pve/thinpools_vms gives an error Logical volume thinpools_vms not found in volume group pve.
After above approach, I have this PV/LV setup showing thinpool_vms_tdata uses all of the fast /dev/sdb3 disk:
  PV         VG  Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda1  pve lvm2 a--   <1.82t 1.52t
  /dev/sdb2           ---       0     0 
  /dev/sdb3  pve lvm2 a--  231.88g    0 
  /dev/sdc2           ---       0     0 
  /dev/sdc3           ---       0     0 

tim@pve2:~$ sudo pvdisplay -m /dev/sdb3
[sudo] password for tim: 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb3
  VG Name               pve
  PV Size               231.88 GiB / not usable 2.16 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              59362
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          59362
  PV UUID               MRdFHX-GRmZ-G4oD-pSYs-57Ao-jl91-2Y7B8K
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 511:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/swap
    Logical extents 0 to 511
  Physical extent 512 to 5631:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/root
    Logical extents 0 to 5119
  Physical extent 5632 to 5658:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/lvol0_pmspare
    Logical extents 0 to 26
  Physical extent 5659 to 59307:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/thinpool_vms_tdata
    Logical extents 0 to 53648
  Physical extent 59308 to 59361:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/thinpool_vms_tmeta
    Logical extents 0 to 53

pvdisplay -m /dev/sda1
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda1
  VG Name               pve
  PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476931
  Free PE               25
  Allocated PE          476906
  PV UUID               4Zg03q-EO4u-kKf9-h2D3-26CV-gbHv-nPwKYY
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 9:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/thinpool_vms_tmeta
    Logical extents 54 to 63
  Physical extent 10 to 46:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/lvol0_pmspare
    Logical extents 27 to 63
  Physical extent 47 to 77469:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/thinpool_vms_tdata
    Logical extents 53649 to 131071
  Physical extent 77470 to 476880:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/thinpool_data_tdata
    Logical extents 0 to 399410
  Physical extent 476881 to 476905:
    Logical volume  /dev/pve/thinpool_data_tmeta
    Logical extents 0 to 24
  Physical extent 476906 to 476930:
    FREE



I very much doubt any part of LVM supports tiered storage of any kind or in any way. The whole point of LVM is to abstract away the underlying physical volume.

I'm not looking for tiered storage, give two PVs underlying my VG, I want to create a thinpool linked to specific PVs. This is possible with above method, but it's cumbersome.

Yes, tiered storage isn't quite the right term. It still is closely related to your goal. Either way, the point stands: this is simply not what LVM is for. Just create two volume groups and spare yourself the trouble. Even with your method, at some point, thin volume chunks will end up on the slow device. This will degrade performance, more-so as fragmentation grows.

Thanks, I realise the caveat you mention (chunks on slow disk), still, with my approach of having a thin volume mostly on the SSD, I will (statistically) have a benefit. Is there a better way to optimize a SSD/HDD combo (in LVM)?
